# SQL Server 2008 error message from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. When we met with such error message from stored procedure,

> Message 1205, Level 13, State 52, the
>   process Pr_FooV2, Line 9 Services
>   (Process ID 111) and another process
>   is deadlock in the lock |
>   communication buffer resources, and
>   has been chosen as the deadlock
>   victim. Rerun the transaction.

I am wondering whether such messages are stored in log files? I searched log folder of my SQL Server 2008 installation root (in my environment, it is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log), but can not find such files.

thanks in advance,

George

Comment: No you'll need to get the deadlock graph by running SQL Profiler and selecting the deadlock graph event (in the locks section). Once you've captured one use the "extract event data" menu option to save it as xdl format.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not how to detect dead lock, but whether there are any ways to let SQL Server log the message itself. Currently I log in my own ASP.Net application.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way of getting it to log specific error numbers. There is an is_event_logged in sys.messages I'm not sure if there is some sysyem sp to change the value. If not you can set up a trace on user error message and filter by error. You can also use the sql server agent alerts to do an action on specific error numbers.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Normally how to log such errors? Should be the responsibility of individual applications to log such specific error in store procedure? How did you normally log such errors?

Comment: Probably depends on the nature of your application. I've mostly worked with web applications where it is easy to log from the application itself. If your application is scattered over client machines though I can see that approach would not be suitable.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed your answer, and it is great! I have some comments and can you help to reply. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL 2008 it looks like you can via `sp_altermessage`.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/05/14/sp-altermessage-is-back-in-business.aspx

Edit: Example to perform batch operation for all messages of severity 14

```
DECLARE @severity INT
SET @severity = 14

declare @dynsql nvarchar(max)

set @dynsql = ''

SELECT   
    @dynsql = @dynsql + 'EXEC sp_altermessage
     @message_id = ' + CAST(message_id AS varchar(10)) + '
    ,@parameter = ''WITH_LOG''
    ,@parameter_value = ''true'' ;
'
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT message_id 
FROM         sys.messages
WHERE  is_event_logged=0 AND severity=@severity
) D

EXEC sp_executesql @dynsql
```

Comment: Cool! But how to turn-on to log all messages (all error messages with different message IDs, and the Url you recommended mentioned only how to turn on logging for a specific message ID)?

Comment: I'll update my post to handle this but you're just going to end up with a load of messages in the event log with absolutely no context to them though if you do that.

Comment: "I'll update my post to handle this" -- thank you and looking forward to your solution! :-)

I am running long-run testing against my database and I need such information.

Comment: Why do you meantion eventlog here? Error message will go to event log and not sql server log folder?

Comment: @George2 Everything that appears in the SQL Error log also shows up in the Windows Event log as far as I know. If all that you want is a bunch of Error messages without any contextual data whilst you test your application you'll probably be better off setting up a SQL Server trace to get these.

Comment: Cool, question answered! Here is another question about SQL Server log, any ideas? :-)

http://serverfault.com/questions/148469/sql-server-2008-log-issue